# OpenFire: In an IQHandler, how to get the authenticated user that sent it?

Tags: authentication, xmpp, packet, openfire

I want to implement an `IQHandler`, but I want to make sure that only authenticated users can send IQ Packets to it. I want to make sure that the JID I get from `Packet.getFrom()` is the authenticated user that sent it.


I need this so that no one can just create an IQ Packet and set the "from" attribute to a user id other than their own. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```java
ClientSession session = sessionManager.getSession(sender);
if(session.getStatus() == Session.STATUS_AUTHENTICATED) {
    //YOUR STUFF HERE
}
```

UPDATE:

Looking closer at the source.  It appears that the IQRouter already does this for you.  If you are not authenticated the server response with an error stating just that.

```java
public void route(IQ packet) {
        if (packet == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        JID sender = packet.getFrom();
        ClientSession session = sessionManager.getSession(sender);
        try {
            // Invoke the interceptors before we process the read packet
            InterceptorManager.getInstance().invokeInterceptors(packet, session, true, false);
            JID to = packet.getTo();
            if (session != null && to != null && session.getStatus() == Session.STATUS_CONNECTED &&
                    !serverName.equals(to.toString())) {
                // User is requesting this server to authenticate for another server. Return
                // a bad-request error
                IQ reply = IQ.createResultIQ(packet);
                reply.setChildElement(packet.getChildElement().createCopy());
                reply.setError(PacketError.Condition.bad_request);
                session.process(reply);
                Log.warn("User tried to authenticate with this server using an unknown receipient: " +
                        packet.toXML());
            }
            else if (session == null || session.getStatus() == Session.STATUS_AUTHENTICATED || (
                    isLocalServer(to) && (
                            "jabber:iq:auth".equals(packet.getChildElement().getNamespaceURI()) ||
                                    "jabber:iq:register"
                                            .equals(packet.getChildElement().getNamespaceURI()) ||
                                    "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind"
                                            .equals(packet.getChildElement().getNamespaceURI())))) {
                handle(packet);
            }
            else {
                IQ reply = IQ.createResultIQ(packet);
                reply.setChildElement(packet.getChildElement().createCopy());
                reply.setError(PacketError.Condition.not_authorized);
                session.process(reply);
            }
            // Invoke the interceptors after we have processed the read packet
            InterceptorManager.getInstance().invokeInterceptors(packet, session, true, true);
        }
```

Comment: I saw this in the source so I also assumed what you're saying. But my concern still remains. It appears that a client can just set the `from` field in the packet for any user, and the server will accept it if that user is authenticated anywhere, not necessarily in the session used to send the packet. So, it feels like `sessionManager.getSession(sender)` will give you a session completely unrelated to the one we are using to send this packet.